# Brave Browser Error: TransportOpenUserCancelled: Access denied to use Ledger device

Tags: hedera-hashgraph

I'm facing the following issue:
`Brave Browser Error: TransportOpenUserCancelled: Access denied to use Ledger device`

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this? Would this be a ledger issue or a Brave browser issue to speak to?

Comment: I tried in chrome browser, relaunching chrome browser, making sure that ledger is unlocked worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Chrome to see if it's a Brave-specific issue (most likely). Basically, you need WebHID or WebUSB support depending on which service you're using.

You can check it here:

- https://caniuse.com/webhid
- https://caniuse.com/webusb